# Silverlight isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

Wanted to know if there was a way to take a folder that is in isolated storage, zip it and make it available for a user to download the zipped file.

Answer (score 2):

Use Silverlight SharpZipLib  http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/

This thread follows someone asking questions as he implements this approach.   Other alternatives are mentioned, but not explored. http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/101789.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The "Mango" SDK ships with the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that can take and restore snapshots of an application's isolated storage to/from a local directory:

```
# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe ts xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"

# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe rs xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"
```